# From time to time Ubuntu 16.04 left and top menu bars disappear and system freezes

Tags: 16.04

I have dual boot: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9550.
Sometimes while Ubuntu is running, left and top menu bars disappear and system freezes. Keyboard does not work, I can't run command line but mouse can still move. In this case I restart system by pushing power button. 
 I can't catch when this happens, it always happens suddenly. After exit from standby or log in everything works.

Any help and advice would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!.